# ruby gsub string phone conversion into specific format

Tags: ruby

i'm trying to convert a phone number using gsub. ""111222333344444" supposed to become "111-222-3333x44444". str.gsub(/^(\d{3})(\d{2,3})(\d{3,4})(\d{4})$/, '\1-\2-\3x\4') returns original string. What am i doing wrong?

Also i converted "W: (111) 222 3333 ext 44") #=> "111-222-3333x44" using the following code. It works, but looks ugly. Is there better way to do it?

```
if str.split.first == "W:"
    first = str.split[1].gsub("(", '').gsub(")", '')
    second = str.split[2]
    third = str.split[3]
    forth = str.split[5]
    first + "-" + second + "-" + third + "x" + forth
else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 15 numbers but your regex only allows for 14 so it won't match. Specifically you've got 4 digits for the extension, but I think you need 5.

```
> str.gsub(/^(\d{3})(\d{2,3})(\d{3,4})(\d{5})$/, '\1-\2-\3x\4')
 => "111-222-3333x44444"
```

Comment: Well it was gonna be you or [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) and I see you have won this time :)

Comment: user13..., `(\d{2,3})` and `(\d{3,4})` in the regex will cause it to match strings having 13, 14 or 15 digits. If 13, group 2 will match 2 digis and group will match 3; if 14, groups 2 and 3 will both match 3 digits (because the regex is *greedy*); if 15, group 2 will match 3 digits and group 3 will match 4. Is that your intent? If the strings always have 15 digits you shoud use `/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{5})$/` (or probably `/\A(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{5})\z/`. Either way, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @engineersmnky Or Cary. 

Comment: @Schwern So true. @CarySwoveland I feel that `/\A(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{3,5})?\z/` would make the most sense for phone number +/- extension (at least in the U.S.)